# GameZero.jl Actor() method unable to use specified image

Tags: julia

When trying out GameZero.jl, the Actor() method is not finding the specified file location.

When entering something like:

```
ship = Actor("C:/path/to/images/image.png"; pos=(100, 100), angle=90)
```

or

```
ship = Actor("./images/image.png"; pos=(100, 100), angle=90)
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty
   @ .\Base.jl:37 [inlined]
 [2] getindex
   @ .\refvalue.jl:56 [inlined]
 [3] file_path(name::String, subdir::Symbol)
   @ GameZero C:...\.julia\packages\GameZero\q74y7\src\resources.jl:46
 [4] image_surface(image::String)
   @ GameZero C:...\.julia\packages\GameZero\q74y7\src\resources.jl:37
 [5] Actor(image::String; kv::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Any, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:pos, :angle), Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Int64}}})
   @ GameZero C:...\.julia\packages\GameZero\q74y7\src\actor.jl:18
 [6] top-level scope
   @ c:...\Documents\practice_gamezero\main.jl:59
```

Why can't it define an actor? I'm simply trying to run the wiki's example code with a placeholder image.

---

Edit:
I am simply trying to run the example project from the wiki:
https://docs.juliahub.com/GameZero/tTDGf/0.3.1/examples/Galaxian/

Edit After Solution:
Do not use a full or even relative path to your image. Making sure to organize the directory as directed, use something like:

```
ship = Actor("image.png"; pos=(100, 100), angle=90)
```

and make sure to call it all using rungame(path/to/main.jl), and not by running main.jl

Comment: Please provide more context: a link to the example you're trying to run, and the full error message you're getting.

Comment: Good suggestions. I have included the link to the example and my error message (using Revise.jl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Actor` takes only the name of the image file as its argument, not its full path.

Since it already knows and expects the file to be in the `images/` subdirectory in the game folder, the argument it needs is just the name of the file, with or without extension.

So the call should be:

```
ship = Actor("image.png"; pos=(100, 100), angle=90)
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Using the suggested directory of having the images, music and sounds sub-directories in the same location as the main.jl file, I get the error using "image.png", "image"(it is used this way at one point in the docs), and the formerly mentioned paths.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it successfully. I'll look into what else might be the cause in your case then.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. I'll mark your answer as accepted, as it is the solution to my question, even if I have other problems as well.

Comment: Could you describe how you're running the game? Is it from the REPL or some other way? What does your `rungame` call look like?

Comment: That question led me to the problem! I had the rungame() call at the end of the main.jl file, meaning I was attempting to run the file in the REPL instead of through rungame(pathtomain). Thank you for helping- not particularly proud myself with this one!

Comment: Glad you found a way that works. But I don't think the previous attempt was a mistake on your part, the docs for `runtime` do say "The zero argument method should be used from the game source file itself when is being executed directly", but with no further details on how exactly the workflow should change in that case. Might be worth opening an issue for.